# The claim that $A \to X$ a cofibration implies $A \times I \to M_{A \to X}$ is an inclusion.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Akhil Matthew claims in https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/cofibrations/ in  parenthesis that given a cofibration, $A \xrightarrow{i} X$, the map $A \times I  \to M_i$ into the mapping cylinder, is an inclusion.

The claim that the map $A \times I$ into  the mapping cylinder $M_i=A \times  I \sqcup_f X$  is an inclusion whenever $i: A \to X$ is a cofibration seems dubious.

This map is an inclusion whenever the map $A \to A \times 1 \to A \times I \sqcup _f X$ is an inclusion, which happens whenever $i$ is injective.

Thus for any noninjective map $A \xrightarrow{j} X$, we have the map $\phi: A \times I \to A \to A \sqcup X_f$.  Then $A \cong A \times 0 \to A \times I \xrightarrow{\phi} \to A \sqcup X /(a ~ f(a)) \hookrightarrow M_i$ is a cofibration such that $A \times I \to M_i$ is not an inclusion.

Is my assesment correct?

Comment: No, cofibrations are injective. See Hatcher 4H.1.

Comment: oh i see the problem.  Everything I said is correct, but the example I gave is not a counterexample to dr. Matthew's statement.  Moreover, what I was trying to do is fundamentally flawed:  I was thinking roughly that - If I pick a particular map from $X \times I$ to some space $B$, then its restriction to $A \times 0 \to X$, will have an extension that lifts the restriction of the homotopy of $X\times I \to B$.  Here's what's wrong: The HE property requires that every map into any choice of $B$ as opposed to a particular one as I have taken above must have an extension.

Comment: (continuation)And this only works when $i$ is an inclusion anyway.  (since restriction doesn't make sense otherwise)

Comment: @MikeMiller [You should turn this into an answer.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23417/10014)